# Using Ruby on Rails, How can I put data in a new table line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm a beginner in Ruby on Rails.
And I'm korean. So my words are little weired...
My question is this...
If I have 10 data, I want to put 1~5th data in a first line and 6~10th data in a second line.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNqhj.jpg)

I've try this codes

```
              <table border height=300 width=300 align=center>
                <thead>
                  <tr style="font size:20;">
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                  <% if current_user.samulham.nil? %>
                    <tr>
                      <% @samulham.each do |x| %>
                         <% if x.user_id.present?%>
                           <td><%= "X" %></td>
                         <% else %>
                           <td><%= link_to "#{x.lockernumber}", {:controller => "home", :action => "register", :cur_user => current_user.id, :cur_samulham => x.id}, method: :post %></td>
                         <% end %>
                      <% end %>
                    </tr>
                  <% end %>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

Thank you for your considering. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your data set size is always 10, you can do it hard coded, something like this:

```
  <tbody>
                      <% if current_user.samulham.nil? %>
                        <tr>
                          <% @samulham.first(5)each do |x| %>
                             <% if x.user_id.present?%>
                               <td><%= "X" %></td>
                             <% else %>
                               <td><%= link_to "#{x.lockernumber}", {:controller => "home", :action => "register", :cur_user => current_user.id, :cur_samulham => x.id}, method: :post %></td>
                             <% end %>
                          <% end %>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <% @samulham.last(5)each do |x| %>
                             <% if x.user_id.present?%>
                               <td><%= "X" %></td>
                             <% else %>
                               <td><%= link_to "#{x.lockernumber}", {:controller => "home", :action => "register", :cur_user => current_user.id, :cur_samulham => x.id}, method: :post %></td>
                             <% end %>
                          <% end %>
                        </tr>
                      <% end %>
     </tbody>
```

EDIT: but if you wanna do it generic for groups of 5 records, you could do something like:

```
@samulham.in_groups_of(5).each do |group|
                        <tr>
                          <% group.each do |x| %>
                             <% if x.user_id.present?%>
                               <td><%= "X" %></td>
                             <% else %>
                               <td><%= link_to "#{x.lockernumber}", {:controller => "home", :action => "register", :cur_user => current_user.id, :cur_samulham => x.id}, method: :post %></td>
                             <% end %>
                          <% end %>
                        </tr>
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much your answer! But, my data set size is usually over 10... I just want to set 5 data in a line.

Comment: @SunHuKim I Edited the post to help to gereralize the solution. Hope it helps you

Comment: It's really help for me!! Thank you very much!